# INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS even when compiling to all supported architectures

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

In Android Studio, I get the error. `INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS` when compiling my app.

In my build.gradle file, I have the following:

```
splits {
    abi {
        enable true
        reset()
        include 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'mips', 'mips64', 'x86', 'x86_64'
        universalApk true
    }
}
```

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html#sa), this is all of the different architectures that exist, so I don't know why it would still throw this error. For reference, I am trying to get my app on a Galaxy S5 using Android Studio 2.2.1 and Gradle 2.2.0.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this error by syncing Gradle to my project.